# Specific css transitioning

Tags: css, image, transition

I want to store some images offscreen, which get activated by a button:active.

Styles:

```
.image {
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: -500px;
    left: 20%;
    transition:0.5s;
 }
 .button1:active .image01 {
    opacity: 1;
    top:5%;
    left:20%;
 }
```

I want them to fade in from opacity 0 to opacity 1.
However, when I put in a transition attribute, it animates both the opacity and the position. Is there any way to only animate the opacity and make the position change instant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add the property (`opacity` in your case) to the transition like this :

```
.image {
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: -500px;
    left: 20%;
    transition:opacity 0.5s;
 }
 .button1:active .image01 {
    opacity: 1;
    top:5%;
    left:20%;
 }
```

---

the transtion has 4 properties than can be defined separately like this :

```
transition-property: opacity; /*Default value is all */
transition-duration: 2s; /* Default value is 0 (no transition effect) */
transition-timing-function: linear; /* Default value is linear */
transition-delay: 1s; /* Default value is 0 */
```

or by using the shorthand property :

```
transition: opacity 2s linear 1s;
```

So if you omit some properties they will take the default values.

Read more about [transition](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)